# How do I use BackgroundSubtractorMOG in OpenCV 3.0.0 with Java?

Tags: java, opencv, computer-vision, background-subtraction

I'm trying to run BackgroundSubtractorMOG on a video file, but the javadoc (Version 3.0.0) says that I need to provide a long as an argument, while the online documentation (Version 2.4.9) says that the constructor requires either no argument, or int,int,double. When I give it a long, I then get an error that the constructor is not visible. Looking into the BackgroundSubtractorMOG class, the constructor is protected, and I have no idea why. I've tried using it both static and non-static methods, but no luck. I have not been able to find a single example of someone successfully using BackgroundSubtractorMOG with java online. Any ideas or examples of how to invoke the constructor?

Comment: It seems they haven't created the Java interface yet.

Comment: Actually, it has gone to the contrib branch. I don't know how to make it work so far.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like here [opencv3.0 creating backgroundsubtractormog2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30288953/creating-backgroundsubtractormog2-in-android-by-opencv-3-0-rc1) they solved it

you need to do it via Video.createBackgroundSubtractorMog2()