# Creating BackgroundSubtractorMOG2 in Android by OpenCV 3.0 RC1

Tags: android, opencv

I'm trying to do background subtraction with MOG2 in OpenCV 3.0 on my android phone. However, it seems that there are no suitable constructor to create a new BackgroundSubtractorMOG2 in version 3.0. My code lies down here.

```
@Override
public void onCameraViewStarted(int width, int height) {
    mFrame = new Mat(height, width, CvType.CV_8UC4);
    mFgMaskMOG = new Mat(height, width, CvType.CV_8UC1);
    pMOG2 = new BackgroundSubtractorMOG2();
}
```

With these codes Android studio reminds me that **the constructor has protected access**. Besides, when I read java src code of BackgroundSubtractorMOG2 I find that **there's one parameter for the constructor: long addr**. The src code as following:

```
protected BackgroundSubtractorMOG2(long addr) { super(addr); }
```

I'm new to OpenCV4Android thus don't know how to construct such a class in java code. Any solution besides using older version of OpenCV4Android?

Answer (score 5):

You can use this code in OpenCV 3.0.0:

```
BackgroundSubtractorMOG2 pMOG2 = Video.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2();
```